# How to disable fields in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My code isn't disabling the other fields. please help
i am trying to select either a participant or exhibitor.once the participant is selected the other fields must be disable.

the Html

```
 <label> <span>Test:</span>
    <select  id="reg" name="reg" onkeyup="disableField()">
      <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Your Registration type  </option> 
      <option value="Male">Participant</option>
     <option value="Female">Exhibitor</option>
    </select>                                   
 </label>


<label> <span>test 1 field:</span>
   <input type="text"  name="test1" id="test1"/>
   </label>
   <label> <span>test field 2:</span>
   <input type="text"  name="test2" id="test2"/>
</label>
```

the javascript

```
   var disableField = function () {
   var state = document.getElementById("reg").value === "Participant";
    document.getElementById("test1").disabled = state;
    document.getElementById("test2").disabled = state;
    };
```

Comment: What did you mean with "disabling the other fields"? Do mean these are not editable?

Comment: i don't want them to be editable

Answer (score 1):

Do not use inline javascript. It makes your code messy and not reusable.

[Edit] This is a working example for you:

```
<html>
   <head> <title></title></head>
   <body>
     <label> <span>Test:</span>
        <select  id="reg" name="reg">
          <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Your Registration type  </option> 
          <option value="Male">Participant</option>
         <option value="Female">Exhibitor</option>
        </select>                                   
     </label>

    <label> <span>test 1 field:</span>
       <input type="text"  name="test1" id="test1"/>
       </label>
       <label> <span>test field 2:</span>
       <input type="text"  name="test2" id="test2"/>
    </label>
   <script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
   var obj = document.getElementById("reg");
   obj.onchange = function(event){
     if(this.value=="Male"){
        document.getElementById("test1").disabled = 'disabled';
        document.getElementById("test2").disabled = 'disabled';
     }else{
        document.getElementById("test1").disabled = '';
        document.getElementById("test2").disabled = '';
     }
   }
   //--></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[/edit]

Have fun and may the source be with you.

Comment: what do i put in the  onchange()??

Comment: You should not use "onchange()" or similar attributes in HTML. The point in the above javascript is, that you fetch your element and give it an onchange function. If your code is not working, be sure to put the javascript on the end of body or it will not find element "reg", becasue it is loaded in body.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use onchange:

```
<select  id="reg" name="reg" onchange="disableField()">
```

Secondly:

Your option values are 'male' and 'female'. So use that to compare:

```
var state = document.getElementById("reg").value == "Male";
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the element to disableFields, when you already got it and instead get it by Id in the function?

Comment: @mondjunge Yes you are right. `this` is the way to go. But, please note that I simply pointed out where he was going wrong. He should not expect readymade code supplied by others. He would be better of by taking hints.

Answer (score 0):

Add an on change in the select list

```
<select  id="reg" name="reg" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged(this)">

function SelectedIndexChanged(e){
    var selectedValue= e.value;
    //if Participant is selected
     if(selectedValue == "Participant "){
      document.getElementById("test1").disabled = true; 
      document.getElementById("test2").disabled = true; 
     }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the element but instead get it from dom? It's bad style.

Comment: @mondjunge Changed it for you. :)

Comment: @Rex: thx, I just wanted to point this out, because everyone seems to do it. In fact I even think onchange attributes are a bad habbit and shpould not be used. But I am a jQuery fan, what else should I say..  ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this ....it is working

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function disableField() {
        var state = document.getElementById("reg").value === "Participant";
        if (state == false) {
            document.getElementById("test1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It cannot work, because value of reg is "Male" or "Female", but never "Participant" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<label> <span>Test:</span>
    <select  id="reg" name="reg" onchange="disableField();">
      <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Your Registration type  </option> 
      <option value="Male">Participant</option>
     <option value="Female">Exhibitor</option>
    </select>                                   
 </label>


<label> <span>test 1 field:</span>
   <input type="text"  name="test1" id="test1"/>
   </label>
   <label> <span>test field 2:</span>
   <input type="text"  name="test2" id="test2"/>
</label>
```

**JS**

```
function disableField() {
    var val = document.getElementById("reg").value;
    if(val == 'Male') {
        document.getElementById("test1").disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById("test2").disabled = true; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test1").disabled = false; 
        document.getElementById("test2").disabled = false; 
    }
}
```

Check value for `Male` not `Participant`

Here is the working code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function disableField() {
                alert('jdhsfg')
                var val = document.getElementById("reg").value;
                if(val == 'Male') {
                    document.getElementById("test1").disabled = true; 
                    document.getElementById("test2").disabled = true; 
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("test1").disabled = false; 
                    document.getElementById("test2").disabled = false; 
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label> <span>Test:</span>
            <select  id="reg" name="reg" onchange="disableField();">
                <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Your Registration type  </option> 
                <option value="Male">Participant</option>
                <option value="Female">Exhibitor</option>
            </select>                                   
        </label>


        <label> <span>test 1 field:</span>
            <input type="text"  name="test1" id="test1"/>
        </label>
        <label> <span>test field 2:</span>
            <input type="text"  name="test2" id="test2"/>
        </label>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this hasn't worked also
    function disableField() {
                var val = document.getElementById("regtype").value;
                 if(val === 'part') {
                document.getElementById("org").disabled = true; 
                document.getElementById("dept").disabled = true; 
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("org").disabled = false; 
                    document.getElementById("dept").disabled = false; 
                }
}

Comment: thank you very much your logic worked but not this code but the reason behind it